# Identifying whether the executor or the driver is OOMing in Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

One of my builds is currently OOMing. In order to better identify next steps for optimisation, I need to identify whether the executor or the driver is OOMing.

What is the best way to determine whether the executor or the driver is OOMing within Foundry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether the executor / driver is OOMing can often be determined through inspecting the build.

When it is likely that the executor is OOMing, the build should show the following error:

[image]

When it is likely that the  driver is OOMing, the build should show the following error:
[image]

Outside of this, a couple of rules that can generally be applied are as follows:

- If the shuffle output location is missing, it is likely that the executor is OOMing.
- If the executor is lost, it is likely that the executor is OOMing.
- If the module is unreachable, it is likely that the driver is OOMing